# python ply parsing to parse function name and the parameter passed to it unambiguously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, ply

```
from ply import lex, yacc
import itertools

reserved = {
        '(?i)fun1' : 'FUN1',
        '(?i)fun2' : 'FUN2'
       }

tokens = [
         'PARAM',
         'FUNC_NAME',
         'LP',
         'RP'
         ]

tokens += reserved.values()

t_PARAM = r'[^\s\(\),&:\"\'~]+'

def t_LP(t):
    r'\('
    return t

def t_RP(t):
    r'\)'
    return t

def t_FUNC_NAME(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.]*'
    if t.value in reserved:
       t.type = reserved[ t.value ]  
    return t

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

t_ignore = ' \t'

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s' on line %d, column %d" % (t.value[0], 
    t.lexer.lineno, t.lexer.lexpos))
    t.lexer.skip(1)

def build_lexer():
    lexer = lex.lex()
    query = "fun1(brownfox)"
    lexer.input(query)
    while True:
        tok = lexer.token()
        if not tok:
           break
        print(tok)

build_lexer()
```

I will have grammar like (yacc grammar rules looks like below):

expression : FUNC_NAME(PARAM)

expression : PARAM

Queries to be parsed for eg are:

1.) `FUN1(parameter1)`

it should be parsed like below:

FUN1 -> FUNC_NAME (as its a reserved word)

parameter1 -> PARAM

2.) `FUN2(parameter2)`

it should be parsed like below:

FUN2 -> FUNC_NAME (as its a reserved word)

parameter2 -> PARAM

3.) `xyz`

it should be parsed like below:

xyz -> PARAM

4.) `fun3(xyz)`

it should be parsed like below:

fun3 -> FUNC_NAME (not a reserved word but its in the form of func_name(param))

xyz -> PARAM

5.) `fun4(xyz)`

it should be parsed like below:

fun4 -> FUNC_NAME (not a reserved word but its in the form of func_name(param))

xyz -> PARAM

But here the problem is the parameter passed to the function name is also parsed as `FUNC_NAME`.

What should i do so that expressions that contains round opening and closing parenthesis should be parsed like function name as `FUNC_NAME` token and parameter as `PARAM` token. Please help.